# Could not get column property.Invalid argument

Tags: excel, vba

Could net get column property. invalid argument

How not to populate the listbox and put all the data in textbox instead? Is there anyway to loop this?

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim say, LastRow As Long

TextBox1 = ListBox1.Column(0)
TextBox2 = ListBox1.Column(1)
TextBox3 = ListBox1.Column(2)
TextBox4 = ListBox1.Column(3)
TextBox5 = ListBox1.Column(4)
TextBox6 = ListBox1.Column(5)
TextBox7 = ListBox1.Column(6)
TextBox8 = ListBox1.Column(7)
TextBox11 = ListBox1.Column(8)
TextBox12 = ListBox1.Column(9)
TextBox13 = ListBox1.Column(10)
TextBox14 = ListBox1.Column(11)
TextBox15 = ListBox1.Column(12)
TextBox16 = ListBox1.Column(13)
TextBox17 = ListBox1.Column(14)
TextBox18 = ListBox1.Column(15)
TextBox19 = ListBox1.Column(16)
TextBox20 = ListBox1.Column(17)
TextBox21 = ListBox1.Column(18)
TextBox22 = ListBox1.Column(19)
TextBox23 = ListBox1.Column(20)
TextBox24 = ListBox1.Column(21)
TextBox25 = ListBox1.Column(22)
TextBox26 = ListBox1.Column(23)

LastRow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
say = ActiveCell.Row
Sheets("Database").Range("A" & say & ":Y" & say).Select
```

Comment: Ofcourse you can loop this, but then it would be easier if your textboxes are chronological as well. You now miss number 9 and 10. For any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following demo:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Test"
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "abc"
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Test2"
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "def"
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim SelectedItem As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ctrls As Variant
    Dim TextBoxCounter As Long

    SelectedItem = ListBoxSelectedIndex(Me.ListBox1)

    ctrls = Array(TextBox1, TextBox2)

    For j = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
        If j <> 9 And j <> 10 And j <= UBound(ctrls) Then
            ctrls(j).Text = Me.ListBox1.List(SelectedItem, TextBoxCounter)
            TextBoxCounter = TextBoxCounter + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
Private Function ListBoxSelectedIndex(lBox As msforms.ListBox) As Long
    With lBox
        For ListBoxSelectedIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(ListBoxSelectedIndex) Then Exit For
        Next ListBoxSelectedIndex
    End With
End Function
```

This produces:

[image: output]

This can be easily expanded with the rest of your controls for your situation